# Angular, Java Service REST

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

Estou tentado fazer a persistência (inserir dados) usando *AngularJS* e *WebService REST* em Java, quando clico em Inserir, no console, aparece o seguinte erro:

> POST http://localhost:8080/Cast_Frotas/rest/curso/insert 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

O que poderia ser?

//WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="2.5">

  <!-- COMO DEFAULT, O NOME DO MEU PROJETO, ESSE NOME IRÁ APARECER NA URL -->
  <display-name>Cast_Frotas</display-name> 

  <!-- MAPEANDO O SERVLET-->
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>br.com.Cast_frotas.service</param-value>
    </init-param> 

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTfull</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

//MEU CONTROLE EM ANGULAR

```
$scope.inserir = function (){
    $http.post(linkservice + "insert", $scope.curso).then(function(data){
        alert('Curso inserido com sucesso!');
    });
}
```

//CLASSE CURSO

```
public class Curso {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String descricao;

    public Curso() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
}
```

//CLASSE CtrlCURSO

```
public class CtrlCurso {

    public boolean insert(Curso c){ 
        return CursoDB.getInstance().insert(c); 
    }

    public List<Curso> getList(){   
        return CursoDB.getInstance().getListAll();  
    }
}
```

//MEU SERVIÇO

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
public void inserirCurso(Curso c){  
    new CtrlCurso().insert(c);
}
```

Comment: Qual biblioteca você está usando para processar o JSON na seu Java WebService?

Comment: Felipe, estou usando JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar a anotação `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`:

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void inserirCurso(Curso c){  
    new CtrlCurso().insert(c);
}
```

Comment: Felipe, obrigado por responder, mais uma vez. Eu estou conseguindo inserir, porém, o objeto chega nulo pro meu serviço, ou seja, insiro tuno nulo. Eu não preciso acessar os valores do json e colocar em variáveis?

Comment: meu código:  @POST
 @Path("/insert")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void inserirCurso(){
  Curso c = new Curso();
  System.out.println(c.getDescricao());
  try{
   new CtrlCurso().insert(c);
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: @MatheusMinguini Por que você você tirou o parâmetro `Curso` do método? É esse parâmetro `Curso` que você vai receber na requisição do Angular. O que você fez no código acima foi criar uma nova instância do objeto `Curso` e não atribuir nenhum valor a suas propriedades. Quando você diz que "insere nulo" seria sobre o seu `getListAll` não retornar nada?

Comment: Retorna sim, retorna um JSON normal! Realmente, eu não me atentei que avia tirado o parâmetro de recebimento da função, porém, após colocar o parâmetro, o erro 415 (Unssuported MediaType) retornou. Mas sim, a minha função getListAll() pega os dados do banco e retorna os mesmos em formato JSON

Comment: @MatheusMinguini Edite sua pergunta e coloque o seu `pom.xml`, `web.xml` e suas classes `CtrlCurso`, `Curso` e `CursoService, por favor.

Comment: editei. Eu não possuo o pom.xml, esse arquivo é para projetos com Maven, certo?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini Sim, é. Você está adicionando todas as dependências na mão? Que coragem! Poderia listá-las para eu testar aqui? Além disso, coloque a classe `CursoService` completa por favor.

Comment: Feipe, eu consegui aqui! Mas muito obrigado, você esteve me ajudando durante o dia todo! Eu estava tentando receber um objeto curso, quando na verdade deveria receber uma String, passá-la para JSON e depois, construir um objeto a partir dos atributos do JSON. OBrigado mesmo, muito sucesso pra você! Como faço para postar o código resolvido?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini Como você tem menos que 100 de reputação, você precisa esperar 8 horas para responder sua pergunta. Além disso, para marcá-la como correta, você precisa esperar 48 horas. [fonte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Quanto a receber como uma `String`, isso não é necessário. O Jersey consegue converter o JSON para um objeto. Você só precisa aplicar uma pequena configuração (que varia de acordo com o processador de JSON que você estiver usando) para que ele faça isso para você. Dê uma olhada [nesse link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html).